# Selenium – Headless Chrome invalid syntax

Tags: selenium, headless

I'm trying to perform a headless Chrome text-scrape, and having problems. Whenever I run the code below I get an error message reading:

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Many thanks in advance!

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("window-size=1400,800");
options.addArguments("headless");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get('https://www.samplehomepage.com')

latest_comment = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p')
print(latest_comment.text)
```

Comment: I see some python with some Java or C#. you can't use two languages in the same script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with java , you can the below code to work on headless chrome browser.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("headless");
options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```